# Error loading lua script for first few lua calls from C application

Tags: lua

**Error in Reloading Master Script. Status 2.**
Getting above error for first 2-3 minutes once traffic is diverted to server.
C server is invoking lua function on each request.
After 2-3 minutes there is no lua error.

Tried to reproduce issue on local setup. But issue is not reproducible on local set up.
On production also issue is random.

Comment: What game you are writing Lua script for?